First person navigation of interior model. Real-time rendering vs gaussian splatting
I've modeled a room with lots of details and it looks great in Cycles (Eevee as well with a bit of tweaking)
Thing is I want the room to be navigable similar to this: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/futuristic-room-a60be41028b049b6a488f5c6effcb6f8 - as if it was a first person game. Problem though is that this doesn't look as good as some of the renders I was able to do in blender with Cycles.
What would be the best way to achieve this? Some research I did:

Real-time rendering: I've looked at trying to simply do this via Eevee, and it's ok (with flickering lights when moving around), but how would I export the Eevee engine for others to enjoy, say on the web? Does something like this even exist (via WebGPU)?
Gaussian Splatting: another idea that came to mind was to just take a lot of pictures of my 3d room and create a guassian splat export which could then be rendered lightly on the web:

Thoughts on the best way to do this? Thanks!
